# What does the expression ${MYVAR:+-x} mean in bash?

Tags: bash, shell, variable-substitution

In a bash script I cannot post here I see the following expression:

```
${MYVAR:+-x}
```

I understand the meaning of expressions like `${MYVAR:+OTHERVAR}` and `${MYVAR:-OTHERVAR}`, but an expression with both a plus-sign and a minus-sign. What does it mean, if anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the same as

```
${MYVAR:+OTHERVAR}
```

with `OTHERVAR` being equal to `-x`. In other words, if `MYVAR` is unset or null, substitute null; otherwise, substitute `-x`.

**References**

- [Parameter Expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_02)